# Line numbers for Optex

Tags: plain-tex, optex

I tried to run [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204334/how-to-automatically-print-line-numbers-for-broken-off-lines-in-plain-tex) (using edmac) with optex but it failed. I know that Optex has the `\ttline` macro, but still couldn't find out how to number text lines.

I started creating a simple macro that would do something like

```
\newcount \linenum
\def\printlinenum{\advance \linenum by 1 \llap{\scalemain\typoscale[800/800]\the\linenum\kern.9em}}
```

But naturally the problem is that it's not counting the lines.

Comment: what did you try? (I mean: a mwe).

Comment: @jarnosz, I tried the answer here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204366/258453 -- as I said, using `\input edmac`. I searched for the definition of `ttline` and `f\_printverblinenum`, and tried to make some changes (see above).

Comment: I believe the `\ttline` macro was designed to number lines in source code, and you want to number lines automatically in regular paragraphs. correct?

Comment: @jarnosz, yes, that's right.

Comment: In my terminal I see that most errors depend on OpTeX's failure to recognize Plain's font commands, and one particular dimension I fear was undefined in OpTeX. Do you get similar errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpTeX doesn't support special macros for this type of numbering, but you can implement your own macros. For example:

```
\newcount\firstlinenum
\newcount\linenumincrement

\def\pstart{\par \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup}
\def\pend{\par \global\tmpnum=\prevgraf \egroup
   \multiply\tmpnum by\linenumincrement \advance\tmpnum by\firstlinenum
   \firstlinenum=\tmpnum \advance\tmpnum by-1
   \setbox0=\vbox{\unvbox0
      \setbox2=\hbox{}
      \loop
         \unskip\unpenalty \setbox1=\lastbox
         \ifvoid1 \else
            \global\setbox2=\hbox{\llap{\printnum}\box1\penalty0\unhbox2}
            \advance\tmpnum by-\linenumincrement 
            \repeat
   }\noindent\unhbox2 \par
}
\def\printnum{\setfontsize{mag.6}\rm\the\tmpnum\kern.8em}

\hsize=3in
\firstlinenum=1
\linenumincrement=1
\pstart
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\pend
\bye
```

The result is equal as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204334).

Comment: Where was OpTeX loaded in this example?

Comment: @janosz: the example can be processed by the command `optex example.tex`.

Comment: right: optex is a format, not a macro package...

Answer (score 3):

OpTeX *may be similar to*, **but it is not based on** Plain TeX; so you may find incompatibilities along the road. You have been warned.

Therefore, in order to use `edmac` along with OpTeX you simply need to load the Plain macros in advance.

```
\input plain
\input edmac
\hsize=3in
\firstlinenum=1
\linenumincrement=1
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end
```

And I guess that's what you tried to achieve.

[image: optex+plain+edmac]

Comment: This is working, but only academical example. Edmac declares its own output routine which deactivates OpTeX's output routine. So several OpTeX functions will be lost (including colors, for example).

Comment: I know: that's exactly why the warning. With OpTeX, as with any alternative format, you have to reimplement the wheel over and over.

Comment: Maybe, I've created better wheel than previous:).

Comment: I won't take away your hope...